# Какие аналоги класса фреймворка Symfony EventDispatcher в Java

Tags: java, symfony

В языке PHP отслеживание событий происходит с помощью класса EventDispatcher, какой класс использовать для этого в Java, попадаются только библиотеки awt и swing. Или можно переопределить данные классы для обработки событий из графических библиотек и не париться?

Comment: приведите примеры событий, которые вы хотели бы отследить

Comment: к примеру добавили новый товар в таблицу БД, я просто не очень понимаю в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Если надо отслеживать добавление со стороны бд - вам в сторону `триггеры бд`. Если просто на факт добавления - добавляйте в метод сохраненеия какой-нибудь класс на основании паттерна `observer`, к примеру. Который будет куда-то отсылать данные/модификации. А там можно запустить к примеру какой-нибудь `TaskExecutor`, который будет эти данные перенаправлять по истечении времени(к примеру на почту, в лог, и т.д.)

Comment: спасибо, буду копать.